# Show that there are more permutations with property $P(r)$ than without

Tags: combinatorics

I'm in stuck with this question. I really appreciate if anyone can help me out.

Let $r, n \in \mathbb{N}$, with $r \leq n$. A permutation $x(1)x(2)\dots x(r)$ of the set $\{1, 2, 3, \dots ,2n\}$ is said to have property $P(r)$ if $|x(i) - x(i-1)| = r$ for at least one $i$ in $\{1 ,2, \dots , 2n\}$.

Show that, for each $n$ and $r$, there are more permutations with property $P(r)$ than without.

I can prove it when $r = n$ but when $r < n$, I don't know how to prove it. For the $r = n$, I use the PIE.

Comment: Well the average number of matches per permutation is $(2n-1)(4n-2r)/(2n(2n-1))$ which is more than 1.  But then you have to deal with more than 1 match in a single permutation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! But I don't really understand your explanation. Could you please give me more information?

Comment: Have you tried proving this by induction?